Meaning of "Would never have thought"

The Englishman had been profoundly impressed by the story. But he would never have thought it more than just a myth..

I could not understand what "would never have thought" means here. Is it like the past form of "will have", the future perfect tense? I do not see any hypothetical situation either because there is no any condition. The man only thought it just a myth.
Later at a time, the man will be told that the story is real and become believing it.
The sentence is from The Alchemist, Paulo Coelho and the translation is the work of Alan R. Clarke, published by HarperOne.

"would have" for past assumptions this might help you

The implication is that  a circumstance has arisen in which he must confront the story as truth, something which he never would have expected to happen.

OP asked about the meaning of "would never have thought" in the sentence from The Alchemist by Paulo Coelho:

But he would never have thought it more than just a myth…

Let's consider the full sentence:

The Englishman had been profoundly impressed by the story.
But he would never have thought it more than just a myth, had not a friend of his—returning from an archaeological expedition in the desert—told him about an Arab that was possessed of exceptional powers. here

The phrase "had not a friend … told him" is an inversion of the conditional clause "if a friend had not told him." This sentence can be rephrased as:
If a friend had not told him, he would never have thought it more than just a myth.
This is a third conditional sentence with the structure:
"If + past perfect, would have + past participle".
Third conditional sentences describe a hypothetical situation in the past that didn’t happen and to imagine how things could have been different if it had happened.
Here, the negative condition implies a hypothetical scenario in which we imagine how things could have been different if something which already happened didn't happen..
The sentence means -
If his friend hadn’t confirmed the story, the Englishman would have continued to believe it was just a myth.
The sentence is complete in itself, with no connection to the future.


would never have thought

This is a common phrase, and could be considered an idiom. It means that the subject is surprised by new information, that they did not predict it.
Here is a EL&U question discussing the same topic.
Meaning in Context

The Englishman had been profoundly impressed by the story. But he would never have thought it more than just a myth..

In this context, this means that the Englishman assumed the story was a myth, not true, and that he was surprised when he learned that it was true.
